# display a button after clicking another button

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-formula

I'm using IBM Domino Designer 9 .
So, I have a "Save" button and another "Create Form" button, when the user clicks "Save", the other button will be displayed

Code button "Save" :

```
@Command([FileSave])
```

Code button "Create Form" :

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim Stream As NotesStream
    Set Stream=Session.CreateStream
    f=Freefile
    fichier="d:\"+Masque.FieldGetText("nomF")+".dxl"
    Open fichier For Output As #f
    Stream.Open(fichier)

    Call Stream.WriteText(|<database xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" version="8.5" maintenanceversion="3.0" replicaid="41257FA4002BD8B9" path="CN=PFE/O=AISA!!E_admini.nsf" title="E_administrateur 2015..2016">|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<databaseinfo dbid="41257FA4002BD8B9" odsversion="43" diskspace="1142784" percentused="75.5600358422939" numberofdocuments="12">|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datamodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datetime dst="true">|+Now+|</datetime>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</datamodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<designmodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datetime dst="true">|+Now+|</datetime>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</designmodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</databaseinfo>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<form name="|+Masque.FieldGetText("nomF")+|" nocompose="true" publicaccess="false" designerversion="8.5.3" recalc="true" renderpassthrough="true">|)
%REM    
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<updatedby>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<name>CN=admin/O=AISA</name>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</updatedby>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<wassignedby>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<name>CN=admin/O=AISA</name>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</wassignedby>|)
%END REM
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<globals>|)
...................
    Stream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is your question? I think it's about how to hide and show a button but please clarify that including what you have tried already :-)

Comment: Why do users need to create forms at all?

Comment: Your question here confuses me because you are showing code for something that is unusual and advanced, but it appears you are asking about something that is very basic. Please describe your entire task in detail.  Showing and hiding buttons is very basic. Using a button to create a Document is also very basic and does not require using DXL. Using a button to create a Form using DXL is extremely unusual and quite advanced. This makes me think that I do not understand your question.

Comment: I have 2 buttons "Save" and "Create Form",
the second button is hidden but when the user clicks on "Save" it will be displayed @RichardSchwartz

Comment: I want to do something that looks like "Google forms" @umeli

Comment: Hmmm... So you are trying to use Domino Designer to make a simple forms designer. I get it now.

Comment: Don't forget, that all the users need to be at least designers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show and hide buttons in a Notes form, you need to use hide-when formulas.

You will need to put your two buttons into a table. That way, they will be in separate paragraphs, so they can have their own hide-when formulas. Your Save button's paragraph will have this hide-when formula:

```
! IsNewDoc
```

The CreateForm button's paragraph will have this hide when formula:

```
IsNewDoc
```

You are also going to have to add a command to your Save button:

```
@Command([FileSave]);
@Command([RefreshHideFormulas]);
```